Graphics problem in 24.04 LTS
I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS inside a Virtual Box on a new Windows 11 host. Clicking on the File Manager on the Desktop (or on related buttons like trash bin or CD) does not show a normal window but just some colored stripes, sometimes blinking. A screenshot is appended. Other applications (terminal, software center, firefox, ...) run without any problem. Can anybody please give me a hint, where this problem may come from?

Have you installed the guest additions?

Yes I did. One problem is that I do not remember how ;.) I followed an instruction saying click on the disc symbol, then do this and that. Now as I said thefile manager also failed for the CD and did not show the directory. So I played around with the graphics driver and the 3D acceleration and the like and finally I was in a state where I could see the contents of the CD and complete the installation. Of course I thought that now my problem was solved but it wasn't.

So you probably didn't install and what you¡re seeing now is a consequence of "playing around". Virtualbox's guest additions for Ubuntu are in the Ubuntu repositories and should be installed from there.

The package is virtualbox-guest-additions-iso.

https://askubuntu.com/a/22745/1210606

I think that the installation of guest additions is OK because afterwards te resizing of the window worked and because of https://askubuntu.com/questions/169024

lsmod | grep vboxguest
vboxguest             219348  6 vboxsf

Is there another way to check? (Sorry, I do not know how to format the terminal stuff properly).

I re-installed the guest additions as you advised, but unfortunately it did not help.

So it's something else but I'm out of ideas.

It looks issues of GTK4.
A work-around is shared here: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/11008

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

The suggested solution was to add export GSK_RENDERER=gl to the .profile or another login script. This did the trick for the file manager, thanks a lot! However, the problem persists for emacs which I use a lot. Is the renderer application specific and if so, how do I set it for one particular application like emacs?

I got exactly the same issue. Some more details on what happens on my configuration:

Host OS is Windows 11 and Guest OS is Ubuntu 24.04.1
VirtualBox version 7.1.4 (and guest additions 7.1.4 too)
Creation of a new ubuntu VM only possible with VBoxSVGA driver (otherwise installation does not start and displays an error). I select VBoxSVGA without checking the "3D acceleration" option
apt update & upgrade
apt intall build-essential dkms
Install guest additions in CDROM
run VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

With this configuration, File Manager displays correctly, but I cannot redimension the virtual screen.
If I stop the machine, select VMSVGA instead and restart: I can redimension the screen, but File Manager does not display.
The process is repeatable

This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can follow this question. Once you have enough reputation, you can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question. - From Review
